# How to slice numpy array such that each slice becomes a new array

Tags: python, numpy

Say there is this array:

```
x=np.arange(10).reshape(5,2)
x=array([[0, 1],
       [2, 3],
       [4, 5],
       [6, 7],
       [8, 9]])
```

Can the array be sliced such that for each row, except the first you combine the rows into a new matrix?

For example:

```
newMatrixArray[0]=array([[0, 1],
       [2, 3]])

newMatrixArray[1]=array([[0, 1],
       [4, 5]])

newMatrixArray[2]=array([[0, 1],
       [6, 7]])
```

This would be easy to do with a for loop, but is there a pythonic way of doing it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We could form all those row indices and then simply index into `x`.

Thus, one solution would be -

```
n = x.shape[0]
idx = np.c_[np.zeros((n-1,1),dtype=int), np.arange(1,n)]
out = x[idx]
```

Sample input, output -

```
In [41]: x
Out[41]: 
array([[0, 1],
       [2, 3],
       [4, 5],
       [6, 7],
       [8, 9]])

In [42]: out
Out[42]: 
array([[[0, 1],
        [2, 3]],

       [[0, 1],
        [4, 5]],

       [[0, 1],
        [6, 7]],

       [[0, 1],
        [8, 9]]])
```

---

There are various other ways to get those indices `idx`. Let's propose few just for fun-sake.

One with `broadcasting` -

```
(np.arange(n-1)[:,None] + [0,1])*[0,1]
```

One with `array-initialization` -

```
idx = np.zeros((n-1,2),dtype=int)
idx[:,1] = np.arange(1,n)
```

One with `cumsum` -

```
np.repeat(np.arange(2)[None],n-1,axis=0).cumsum(0)
```

One with *list-expansion* -

```
np.c_[[[0]]*(n-1), range(1,n)]
```

Also, for performance, use `np.column_stack` or `np.concatenate` in place of `np.c_`.

Comment: Neat! Indexing a 2D array with another 2D array bends my mind a little.

Comment: Would this also be possible with np.r_ ?

Comment: @Alex Well we are dealing with 2D indexing array. We use `np.r_` to form 1D arrays. So, I am not sure if/how we could use that in here.

Comment: My mistake, did not read the fine print in the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

My approach would be a list comprehension:

```
np.array([
    [x[0], x[i]]
    for i in range(1, len(x))
])
```

Comment: I suppose I'd call this pythonic, but [Divakar's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3293881/divakar) is definitely more numpythonic.