# Indexing with lists and arrays in numpy appears inconsistent

Tags: python, numpy, indexing

Inspired by [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46116345/how-to-slice-numpy-array-such-that-each-slice-becomes-a-new-array/46116440#46116440), I'm trying to wrap my mind around [advanced indexing](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/arrays.indexing.html#advanced-indexing) in NumPy and build up more intuitive understanding of how it works.

I've found an interesting case. Here's an array:

```
>>> y = np.arange(10)
>>> y
array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
```

if I index it a scalar, I get a scalar of course:

```
>>> y[4]
4
```

with a 1D array of integers, I get another 1D array:

```
>>> idx = [4, 3, 2, 1]
>>> y[idx]
array([4, 3, 2, 1])
```

so if I index it with a 2D array of integers, I get... what do I get?

```
>>> idx = [[4, 3], [2, 1]]
>>> y[idx]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
IndexError: too many indices for array
```

Oh no! The symmetry is broken. I have to index with a 3D array to get a 2D array!

```
>>> idx = [[[4, 3], [2, 1]]]
>>> y[idx]
array([[4, 3],
       [2, 1]])
```

What makes numpy behave this way?

To make this more interesting, I noticed that indexing with numpy arrays (instead of lists) behaves how I'd intuitively expect, and 2D gives me 2D:

```
>>> idx = np.array([[4, 3], [2, 1]])
>>> y[idx]
array([[4, 3],
       [2, 1]])
```

This looks inconsistent from where I'm at. What's the rule here?

Comment: I think [this might be a good point to start from](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/arrays.indexing.html#advanced-indexing), although I'm also at a loss explaining the behaviour

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46116568/numpy-array-indexing-list-index-and-np-array-index-give-different-result) was asked half an hour ago and seems quite relevant here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason is the interpretation of lists as index for numpy arrays: Lists are interpreted like tuples and indexing with a tuple is interpreted by NumPy as multidimensional indexing.

Just like `arr[1, 2]` returns the element `arr[1][2]` the `arr[[[4, 3], [2, 1]]]` is identical to `arr[[4, 3], [2, 1]]` and will, according to the rules of multidimensional indexing return the elements `arr[4, 2]` and `arr[3, 1]`.

By adding one more list you do tell NumPy that you want slicing along the first dimension, because the outermost list is effectively interpreted as if you only passed in one "list of indices for the first dimension": `arr[[[[4, 3], [2, 1]]]]`.

From the [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#purely-integer-array-indexing):

> #### Example
>
> From each row, a specific element should be selected. The row index is just [0, 1, 2] and the column index specifies the element to choose for the corresponding row, here [0, 1, 0]. Using both together the task can be solved using advanced indexing:
>
> ```
> >>> x = np.array([[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]])
> >>> x[[0, 1, 2], [0, 1, 0]]
> array([1, 4, 5])
> ```

[and](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#advanced-indexing):

> #### Warning
>
> The definition of advanced indexing means that `x[(1,2,3),]` is fundamentally different than `x[(1,2,3)]`. The latter is equivalent to `x[1,2,3]` which will trigger basic selection while the former will trigger advanced indexing. Be sure to understand why this occurs.

In such cases it's probably better to use [`np.take`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.take.html):

```
>>> y.take([[4, 3], [2, 1]])  # 2D array
array([[4, 3],
       [2, 1]])
```

> This function [`np.take`] does the same thing as “fancy” indexing (indexing arrays using arrays); however, it can be easier to use if you need elements along a given axis.

Or convert the indices to an array. That way NumPy interprets it (`array` is special cased!) as fancy indexing instead of as "multidimensional indexing":

```
>>> y[np.asarray([[4, 3], [2, 1]])]
array([[4, 3],
       [2, 1]])
```